# BlockUI not working after the first call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-blockui

I am using blockUI with some AJAX calls and am running into issues with it working. The first time it is called everything works as expected. When I execute a subsequent AJAX call and try to call blockUI it does not block my screen again. In both cases writing to console results in function (opts) { install(window, opts); } being returned. Thinking that it might be a z-value issue I've tried adding baseZ with a number higher than any other z-value in my css but that didn't correct it. A simple instance of one of the calls is below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click',".defect",function() {
        $.blockUI({ message: "<h4>Getting images ...</h4><img src='img/wait.gif'/>"});
    })
})
```

I have tried `$(document).ajaxStop($.unblockUI);` and then tried removing that and using `$.unblockUI();` in my AJAX success but still had the same results

Comment: What you have should more or less work. Can you include a more complete example of what you're doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add jquery.blockUI.js .Try adding it when ajax call happens:

```
$(document)
    .ajaxStart(function () {
    $.blockUI(); 
/*      for css style
    $.blockUI({css: { border: 'none',
            padding: '5px',
            backgroundColor: '#000',
            '-webkit-border-radius': '5px', 
            '-moz-border-radius': '5px',
            opacity: .5, color: '#fff' },
            message: "Loading..."}); */
    })
    .ajaxStop(function () {
     $.unblockUI();
    });
```